# Does Apple specify what the average lifespan of an iMac G5 would be?

Tags: imac

Based solely on the hardware used (including the power supply, logic board, RAM...) and assuming that the Software will not be updated (remain at **OS X Tiger** does Apple specify what a reasonable expectation for the lifespan of an **iMac G5 from Mid 2005** would be?

Does (or has) Apple provided specifications such as these for any of its products?

I am looking into purchasing one from eBay and want to know if it will last and if I can expect to receive one that is "fully functional" even after ten years.

Comment: Would love to help you, but we can not tell the condition you will get from ebay. For example, when was the thermal paste replaced?

Comment: Assuming it was stock (no upgrades / no extensive cleaning / nothing along the lines of reapplying the thermal paste) just daily / common wear and general use for the past 10+ years. Most of the listing write good condition and that it works, I am wondering if I should expect any problems with it should I decide to purchase one... Thanks for the help!

Comment: out of interest how much? I would guess keyboard will go soon, a cooling fan, a hard drive, not in that order, probably CPU will overheat one day. 10+ is at the limit of the Integrated circuits life time (the chips on the logic board).

Comment: look here to learn more https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624

Comment: They are priced roughly around $100 - $150, my interest in buying one is for replaying old PowerPC games (I used to have one as a kid) so it wouldn't have to withstand daily use...

Comment: @GhostKoi Reading your descriptions of the use, I'd say these are quite easily repairable and you can get lots of advice from ex-Apple genius on how to work on that model. Since it's for running old games, you can buy several dead carcasses for $25 and stockpile the parts you may need and recycle the rest.

Comment: @bmike Not a bad idea... I will probably end up buying one from eBay and (assuming I do have trouble with it later on) buy parts / upgrade later on. Aside from the Apple Genius Bar (which won't help in this case) do you know of any good resources for this, forums etc... I found some help on iFixit but not much else... thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Apple actually disclaims that a brand new Mac will work reliably. Only that they will repair it, replace it, or refund your purchase if you seek warranty service under the conditions of the one year warranty:

> APPLE DISCLAIMS ALL STATUTORY AND IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND WARRANTIES AGAINST HIDDEN OR LATENT DEFECTS

<sup>Above from the US hardware warranty page at http://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/ for a Mac Pro</sup>

Furthermore, Apple has a long standing policy of cutting off the vast majority of repair service for Macs 5 years from the date when they remove it from sale.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201624 - Vintage and obsolete products

There are some exceptions where you can get support between years 5 and 7, but after 7 years, Apple and Apple Authorized Service Centers often flat out deny repair requests due to lack of support or part availability.

I cannot find any G5 or PPC machine that isn't officially designated by Apple as obsolete in 2015.

So - in summary, a new Mac Pro isn't sold with the expectation that it will even work for one year and the expectation that it might need repairs. Certainly second hand older machines won't be vouched for by Apple to have a working life of 10 years from now. That doesn't mean some G5 will run for decades to come, just that the one you buy might or might not be the exception to things wearing out eventually.